# Incrementing number inside bloc string using fwrite

Tags: php, mysql

im creating file retrieving data from mysql database.

```
$fo = fopen($newName, 'w')or die("can't open file")
```

After querying db, lets start writing.

```
<?php fwrite($fo, $row['entetequestionmonochoix']. PHP_EOL);?>
```

Correspondance to 'entetequestionmultichoix' is the following:

```
\begin{question}{01}\scoring{b=1,e=0,m=0,V=0}
```

im facing a small obstacle when generating file.

The while loop allow me to read and then insert but inside the correspondance i need to increment **{01}** after each loop.

```
\begin{question} **{01}**\scoring{b=1,e=0,m=0,V=0}
```

Comment: You can use `str_replace()` to replace `{01}` with an incrementing variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace()` to replace `{01}` with a string containing an incrementing variable.

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $line = str_replace('{01}', sprintf('{%02d}', $i++), $row['entetequestionmonochoix']);
    fwrite($fo, $line . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: thanks. ill try it later. i noticed that   \begin{question} **{01}**\scoring{b=1,e=0,m=0,V=0}                    is a constant, so i splitted like this:                                                                                        
                     <?php fwrite($fo, "\begin{question}{");?>    <?php  
                     $var += 1;

                        fwrite($fo,$var);
                      ?>
                     <?php   fwrite($fo,"}\scoring{b=1,e=0,m=0,V=0} ". PHP_EOL);?>